# Unable to select voices using SpeechSynthesizer.SelectVoice() method

Tags: c#, select, voice, speech, synthesis

I'm trying to make a text-to-speech application where I can select the voice via a combobox and have some text read out in that voice.

I'm getting the names of available voices to populate the combobox by using the following:

```
    private List<String> getInstalledVoices()
    {
        var installedVoices = new List<String>();

        using (SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer())
        {
            foreach (InstalledVoice voice in synth.GetInstalledVoices())
            {
                installedVoices.Add(voice.VoiceInfo.Name);
            }
        }
        return installedVoices;
    }
```

I then set the combobox's DataSource property to the resulting list.

Now, my issue is when it comes to actually reading the text, it will ONLY read it out in one voice, regardless of what is selected. Using the debugger I can see that when the program arrives at synth.SpeakAsync() the synth's voice is correctly set to the right values, but the voice just doesn't change when it's read out.

I don't get any errors or anything!

```
    private void speak(String toSpeak)
    {
        SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        synth.SelectVoice(voiceSelectionBox.SelectedItem.ToString());
        PromptBuilder promptBuilder = new PromptBuilder();
        promptBuilder.AppendText(toSpeak);
        synth.SpeakAsync(promptBuilder);            
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?!

Installed voices -
 Name:          Microsoft Hazel Desktop
 Culture:       en-GB
 Age:           Adult
 Gender:        Female
 Description:   Microsoft Hazel Desktop - English (Great Britain)
 ID:            TTS_MS_EN-GB_HAZEL_11.0
 Enabled:       True
 No supported audio formats found
 Additional Info -   Age: Adult
  Gender: Female
  Language: 809
  Name: Microsoft Hazel Desktop
  SharedPronunciation: 
  SpLexicon: {0655E396-25D0-11D3-9C26-00C04F8EF87C}
  Vendor: Microsoft
  Version: 11.0

Name:          eSpeak-en+f2
 Culture:       en-US
 Age:           Adult
 Gender:        Male
 Description:   eSpeak-EN+F2
 ID:            eSpeak_1
 Enabled:       True
 No supported audio formats found
 Additional Info -   Name: eSpeak-en+f2
  Gender: Male
  Age: Adult
  Language: 409
  Vendor: http://espeak.sf.net

Name:          eSpeak-en-us
 Culture:       en-US
 Age:           Adult
 Gender:        Male
 Description:   eSpeak-EN-US
 ID:            eSpeak_2
 Enabled:       True
 No supported audio formats found
 Additional Info -   Name: eSpeak-en-us
  Gender: Male
  Age: Adult
  Language: 409
  Vendor: http://espeak.sf.net

Name:          eSpeak-en
 Culture:       en-US
 Age:           Adult
 Gender:        Male
 Description:   eSpeak-EN
 ID:            eSpeak
 Enabled:       True
 No supported audio formats found
 Additional Info -   Name: eSpeak-en
  Gender: Male
  Age: Adult
  Language: 409
  Vendor: http://espeak.sf.net

Name:          Microsoft David Desktop
 Culture:       en-US
 Age:           Adult
 Gender:        Male
 Description:   Microsoft David Desktop - English (United States)
 ID:            TTS_MS_EN-US_DAVID_11.0
 Enabled:       True
 No supported audio formats found
 Additional Info -   Age: Adult
  Gender: Male
  Language: 409
  Name: Microsoft David Desktop
  SharedPronunciation: 
  SpLexicon: {0655E396-25D0-11D3-9C26-00C04F8EF87C}
  Vendor: Microsoft
  Version: 11.0

Name:          Microsoft Zira Desktop
 Culture:       en-US
 Age:           Adult
 Gender:        Female
 Description:   Microsoft Zira Desktop - English (United States)
 ID:            TTS_MS_EN-US_ZIRA_11.0
 Enabled:       True
 No supported audio formats found
 Additional Info -   Age: Adult
  Gender: Female
  Language: 409
  Name: Microsoft Zira Desktop
  SharedPronunciation: 
  Vendor: Microsoft
  Version: 11.0

Name:          VW Julie
 Culture:       en-US
 Age:           Adult
 Gender:        Female
 Description:   VW Julie
 ID:            VW Julie
 Enabled:       True
 No supported audio formats found
 Additional Info -   Age: Adult
  Gender: Female
  Language: 409;9
  Vendor: Voiceware
  Name: VW Julie

Comment: Having more than one voice available is pretty unusual, the OS only ever provides one.  Get ahead by describing what other ones you see and where you purchased them.

Comment: @HansPassant I've updated my post. (I can use these other voices in 3rd party TTS applications)